# Issue with reading Heroku hosted discord.py bot token from .env file

Tags: python, heroku, environment-variables, discord.py

I have no issues with Heroku when I put the token directly into the main code. And my code works on my own computer when I hide the token in my .env file. But when I run it with Heroku, I get these errors in my Heroku logs:

```
2020-08-22T16:27:49.125385+00:00 app[worker.1]: await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
2020-08-22T16:27:49.125400+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

So basically, it is not reading my token at all. And then the status changes to crashed. Here is how I am reading the token:

```py
import os
import dotenv 
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
```

I have checked and the token is read properly on my computer.

Comment: Did you add your token to your config vars in heroku?

Comment: @jreiss1923 I just added it and it is fixed! Thank you!

Comment: No problem happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this wasn't working is because the token was not added to the config variables in heroku. To do this, navigate to the settings page for your project, click on "Add Config Vars", and add your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't read your `.env` file. I usually see those as used to load an environment in development or test, but not in production. You can set the environment variable at the "Settings" tab on the Heroku dashboard, or you can set it from your terminal with Heroku's CLI:

```sh
heroku config:set DISCORD_TOKEN=myvalue
```

You can check your environment variables with:

```sh
heroku config
```

Or you can check one environment variable with

```sh
heroku config:get DISCORD_TOKEN
```